# Hide all Buttons in WPF Application

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, binding

I have an WPF C# application with some views (xaml), inter alia an option view. In this view there is a checkbox to hide all buttons.

The problem, how to do that?

I have an `MainStyle.xaml` which is an `ResourceDictionary` and contains all styles, converters and so on. My approach is to set a style in this file like:

```
<Style TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
</Style>
```

This works, but the user should decide if the buttons are visible or not. So I have to bind the style to the checkbox.

**The first step** will be to bind the style to the code behind of the ResourceDictionary (MainStyle.xaml). But it doesn't work. I've set the property in the constructor to false, but the Buttons are visible.

**MainStyle.xaml**

```
<Style TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="Visibility" 
            Value="{Binding ButtonsEnabled, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ResourceDictionary}, Converter={StaticResource BooleanVisibilityConverter}}" />
</Style>
```

**Code Behind (MainStyle.xaml.cs)**

```
public partial class BaseStyle : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public BaseStyle()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ButtonsEnabled = false; // for testing
    }

    private Boolean buttonsEnabled;


    public bool ButtonsEnabled
    {
        get { return buttonsEnabled; }
        set
        {
            buttonsEnabled = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("ButtonsEnabled");
        }
    }

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

If the binding works, the second step would be to bind the style in the ResourceDictionary to the options view.

Comment: Firstly check your VS Output window to search for bindings that have failed.  Then fire up Snoop and check the Visibility property for a button to see if it has failed (highlighted in Red).  If you can find out what has actually failed then you can start to put in the correct solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't locate the checkbox directly from the binding, then an attached property with inheritance would work for you. For example, the following XAML:

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfSpikes.InheritedAttachPropertyView" x:Name="View"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfSpikes"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BooleanToVisibilityConverter"/>
        <Style x:Key="VisibleButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=(local:ButtonVisibility.IsVisible), Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"/>
        </Style>
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <CheckBox Content="Show Buttons?" IsChecked="{Binding ElementName=View, Path=(local:ButtonVisibility.IsVisible), Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
        <Button Grid.Row="1" Content="Button1" Style="{StaticResource VisibleButtonStyle}"/>
        <Button Grid.Row="2" Content="Button2" Style="{StaticResource VisibleButtonStyle}"/>
        <Button Grid.Row="3" Content="Button3" Style="{StaticResource VisibleButtonStyle}"/>
        <Button Grid.Row="4" Content="Button4" Style="{StaticResource VisibleButtonStyle}"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Uses this attached property:

```
public static class ButtonVisibility
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsVisibleProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("IsVisible", typeof(bool), typeof(ButtonVisibility), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(true, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.Inherits));

    public static bool GetIsVisible(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (bool)obj.GetValue(IsVisibleProperty);
    }

    public static void SetIsVisible(DependencyObject obj, bool value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(IsVisibleProperty, value);
    }
}
```

To control button visibility.

Note that the attached property specifies `FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.Inherits` and the combobox binds to this property on the element named `View` (i.e. the top level user control). The button style then binds to this property at the level of each individual button (using `RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}`) which, as the buttons are within the UserControl, pick up the inherited value of IsVisible.

Works for me. Hope it helps.